# Garbage Collection on circular objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

In my [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) node.js server, I have it so that when a client connects, it assigns a "user" object to their [websocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#class-wswebsocket) object, and inside that user object is a reference back to their websocket object. This lets me send data to a client when I only know their user object (all game logic only deals in user objects, not websockets), and it lets me get a client's user information when data comes in from their websocket object.

I've heard that circular objects can cause issues where garbage collection will never clean them up because they have references to each other, **so my question is,** what do I need to do to make sure that when a client disconnects, their websocket and user objects both get properly removed from memory?

Also, let me know if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way! :P

---

**Edit:** Code:

```
function onConnect(client) {
    users.push({connected: true, client: client, name: "", messages: 0});
    client.user = users[users.length - 1];
    send("Please enter a username.", [client.user]);
}
```

Comment: I have worked with circulair objects. If you only refer one-way there are most of times no problems. Let say you have a "Master" and "Detail". The "Detail" depends of the master, so if you have the "Master" then you also have the "Details". The problems arise if you also wants to go from the "Detail" to the master. The problem is the "relation" from "Master" to "Detail" and "Detail" to Master, thats circulair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually remove closed connections from the list. Otherwise, garbage collector will not remove them from memory.

```
function onConnect(client) {
  users.push({
    connected: true,
    client: client,
    name: "",
    messages: 0
  });
  client.user = users[users.length - 1];
  client.on('close', function(){
    //remove closed connection from the list then let garbage collector does its job.
    users.splice(users.indexOf(client.user), 1);
  });
  send("Please enter a username.", [client.user]);
}
```

Comment: So the websocket object will no longer have a reference to the user object once it's spliced out of the users array? Or should I also do `client.user = null` after the splice? And do I need to do.. `client.user.client = null`?

Comment: @ShaunDreclin It's not neccessary since `user` is a property of `client` object.

Comment: Ohh I see, and does the client object delete itself after the close event?

Comment: delete from memory? I guess no. BTW, you shouldn't be your concern.

Comment: Well if the server is running for an extended period of time I don't want memory getting filled up by old client objects. I guess that falls on the developer of ws though, they've probably taken care of it?

Comment: Garbage collector will take care of it, not `ws` devs. In this case, it is V8's GC. As I mentioned, your job is to remove closed connections from `users`. Then GC will remove them from memory at the appropriate time.

Comment: Huh I dunno why I never marked this as the accepted answer, it solved my issue. Very belated thanks!